# preg_match_all for dates with different format

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a preg_match to get dates from a string:

```
preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}/',$myString,$dates);
```

This will get dates with the syntax:

```
01.01.2022
1.01.2022
1.1.2022
1.1.22
...
```

Now I have a date format like this:

```
25 März 2023
or
25 March 2023
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Are these 25 März 2023 dates in a string as well? and how do they look like in a string

Comment: could you try this `preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\s\w+\s\d{2,4}/',$myString,$matches);`

Comment: doesnt work :/ preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\s\w+\s\d{2,4}/', 'This is a 25 März 2023 test', $matches);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
\b\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2}\.|\h+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\h+)(?:\d\d|\d{4})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.\d{1,2}\.` Match `.` 1-2 digits `.`
  - `|` Or
  - `\h+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\h+` Match any uppercase char followed by 1+ lowercase chars between 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?:\d\d|\d{4})` Match 2 or 4 digits
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9CJZXA/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Waoir).

```
$re = '/\b\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2}\.|\h+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\h+)(?:\d\d|\d{4})\b/u';
$str = '01.01.2022
1.01.2022
1.1.2022
1.1.22
...
Now I have a date format like this:

25 März 2023
or
25 March 2023';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01.01.2022
    [1] => 1.01.2022
    [2] => 1.1.2022
    [3] => 1.1.22
    [4] => 25 März 2023
    [5] => 25 March 2023
)
```